# Windows Phone 8 Shoutcast not playing

Tags: windows-phone-8, streaming, windows-phone, shoutcast

I am making an app which plays a Shoutcast stream but I cannot get the stream to play. I know the code works for other streams.

How do I get the Shoutcast stream to work?

Here's the code from the audio playback agent:

```
private void play(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
    {
        if (player.Track == null)
        {

            player.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri(streamURL, UriKind.Absolute), "Show", "Station", "", null);
        }

        player.Volume = 1;


        if (player.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing)
        {

            player.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried? show some code.

Comment: What URL are you using?  Have you tried requesting `/;` from the server?

Comment: Yeah I've tried /; and /;.mp3 and neither of them worked the url is http://87.117.201.159:8050

Answer (score 1):

see an example : 
http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/
ShoutCasts are not very easy to stream .